# Через раз работает CIblockElement::Update

Tags: php, битрикс, cms, 1с

Для элементов инфоблока нужно обновить PREVIEW_PICTURE и DETAIL_PICTURE.
Изображения уже находятся на сервере.
Делаю так:

```
$picture = CFile::MakeFileArray($path_to_picture);
$arLoadProductArray = Array(
    "PREVIEW_PICTURE" => $picture,
    "DETAIL_PICTURE" => $picture,
);

$res = $el->Update($elem["ID"], $arLoadProductArray);
if($res)
    echo "OK";
else
    print_r($el->LAST_ERROR)
```

Но почему-то изобажения меняются через раз. А бывает, что измениться только PREVIEW_PICTURE, а DETAIL_PICTURE нет. Или наоборот. А может вообще ни то, ни другое.

Update всегда возвращает true.

Comment: Приведите чуть более полный фрагмент кода. Откуда взялась переменная `$el` ?

Comment: $el = new CIBlockElement;

Comment: Проблема не в коде, скорее всего. Ибо в таблице b_iblock_element имеется ID c картинкой, но у этого же ID  в таблице b_file пустые поля.

Comment: А пробовали в $picture просто передавать путь к файлу строкой? Такая же проблема или все ок? Потому что для появления записи в b_file нужен метод SaveFile после использования MakeFileArray. Если файл уже точно на сервере то используйте метод `GetFileArray()` вместо MakeFileArray.

Comment: не выходить, всё тоже самое получается...странно

Comment: Запустил этот же скрипт на другом сервере и там все заработало. Не знаю почему...